# CURL wont load data from https

Tags: php, curl

My xampp wont load anything on this, I tried it on gearhost, same thing, but on one other free host, it worked.. json was loaded as it should.

Here's the code

```
$username= urlencode($_GET["username"]);
$endpoint = 'https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';
// create the xml request that will be POSTed
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xml .= '<GetStoreRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
$xml .= '<RequesterCredentials>';
$xml .= '<eBayAuthToken></eBayAuthToken>';
$xml .= '</RequesterCredentials>';
$xml .= '<UserID>'. $username .'</UserID>';
$xml .='<LevelLimit>1</LevelLimit>';
$xml .= '</GetStoreRequest>';
$headers = array(
     'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:933',
'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:--',
'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:--',
'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:--',
'X-EBAY-API-SITEID:0',
'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:GetStore'
    );

    $session  = curl_init($endpoint);                     
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);             
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml); 
  curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);   
  $responsexml = curl_exec($session);                   
  curl_close($session);  

     $json = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($responsexml),true);
     $obj = json_decode($json,true);
    echo $responsexml; 
    echo $obj;
```

Comment: you're simply assuming curl never fails. `if ($responsexml === false) { die(curl_error($session)); }`

Comment: nothing.. blank page.. only when I echo $json i get "false" thats all

Comment: the thing is.. it works on some free hosting.. but not on my xampp.. or my realhosting..

Comment: @MarcB Tried it.. still blank page.. Could it be hosting related issue? I mean it must be.. since same code runs on byethost. I contacted support they told me curl is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$compatabilityLevel = 859;     
$return_api_host = 'https://api.ebay.com/ws/api.dll';
$callName = 'GetStore'; //this is changed based on what call you are making

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type: text/xml',
    'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: '.$compatabilityLevel,
    'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: '.$devID,
    'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: '.$appID,
    'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: '.$certID,
    'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: '.$callName,
    'X-EBAY-API-SITEID: 0',
    'SOAPAction: "run"');


    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $return_api_host);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlpost);
    //get response from server
    $response =curl_exec($curl);
    //format response in array
    $responsexml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
```

obviously the $xmlpost element will include your xml being sent.
and you can do a print_r($responsexml) to see results.

Comment: A little explanation of what you added and why would probably help the OP more than just giving them the code

Comment: well this is working code i use for ebay so i think this would help. i think the difence is in the  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); and curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Comment: @md123 tried adding those two, still blank page. It seems to me it might be hosting related problem. But the tech support guy claims curl is active. This same code wont run on my local machine but it is on some 3rd server I tried..

Comment: **Dont tell me** Put it in your answer. Remember this answer can be seen by others that may have the same problem. Each of whom may also give it an upvote if it is a good well put together answer that explains why these extra parameters are needed in this situation.

Comment: @perkes456  i dont see you pointing your curl to a server..? try adding  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $return_api_host);

Comment: make sure you have all the options as i do in my curl if you are missing 1 it wont work.

Comment: @md123 whats $return_api_host ?

Comment: @perkes456  $return_api_host  seeabove